# Using DatagramChannel to send video in java

Tags: java, video, stream

I am trying to implement a simple server-client model to stream video. The video which is being played on server should play in client as well. I searched over the net and found that DatagramChannel in java is suitable for this. How can I send video with DatagramChannel? Or is there any other solution? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ready solutions like Red5 server or FFMPEG-Java

Comment: is Red5 working on Windows 7? Can I add the plugin to the eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use DatagramChannel as,

- its not suitable for braodcast over the internet,
- its not a reliable protocol. It can be made reliable but this is not easy.

Instead I would use TCP. There are many libraries which help do with including Netty and Mina.

Comment: I will look at these libraries. Which one do you prefer mostly?

Comment: This is wrong advice to use TCP over UDP for streaming multimedia data. The reliability semantics of TCP will provide low fidelity and will even close the connection if it looses too many packets - this is not ideal for sending codec data. UDP is much more forgiving but at the expense of order, loss, error and correction; however you could write a simple protocol to deal its limitations or use a standard protocol like Real-time Transport Protocol.

Comment: @algolicious So you are saying the biggest video streaming providers like YouTube, NetFlix, Hulu or Vevo use UDP or TCP? I always thought it was TCP.

Comment: It looks like YouTube uses RTSP over UDP for the media stream. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol